# How to use filter() on a string and get multiple word occurences?

Tags: python, lambda

I was able to capture the first instance, but trying to get either a count or just duplicate in the returned `sets`

For example, here is my code simplified,

```
word_list = ['Geico','Mike']
a_string = "what day is it, Mike Mike Mike"
sets = filter(lambda x:x in a_string,word_list)
```

... I get `['Mike']` but would like to get `['Mike','Mike','Mike']`; just some way to better understand how to iterate within filter if possible. I probably do not need each "Mike" for my project, but understanding this **will help me wrap my head around the use of filter() with lambda**; so improving this code is more important to me than a new way of doing it.

Comment: You can't expect to get three "Mike"s if you're filtering from something that contains it only once.

Comment: you are doing the opposite
print filter(lambda x: x in word_list, li)
filter(needle,haystack)

Comment: @StefanPochmann I don't know filter() so well, but there a lot of things that can do DRY processing. Ajay ended up explaining it really well in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Understaning Filter:**

You are searching otherway around.
You should do this `filter(needle,haystack)`
but you are doing    `filter(haystack,needle)`

Example

```
>>> names = ['Anna', 'Grant', 'Bob', 'David', 'Carrie', 'Barbara', 'Zach']
>>> b_names = filter(lambda s: s.startswith('B'), names)
>>> print b_names
#Output
['Bob', 'Barbara']
```

`filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to [`item for item in iterable if function(item)]` **if function is not None** and `[item for item in iterable if item]` **if function is None**.

**Understanding lamba:**
`lambda` is just another word for `function` When you read the following line, replace `lambda` by `function` in your mind:

```
>>> f = lambda x: x + 10
>>> f(3)
13
```

Example:2

```
f = lambda x, y : x * y
```

The above function is equivalent to the one below.

```
def f(x, y):
    return x * y
```

`lambda` returns a function that given the parameters to the left of the `:` sign will return the value of the expression on the right of it.
More about lambda in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-python-lambdas-are-useful)

```
from collections import  Counter


word_list = ['Geico','Mike']
a_string = "what day is it, Mike Mike Mike"
li=a_string.split()
print Counter(li)
print [i for i in li if i in word_list]

Output:
Counter({'Mike': 3, 'what': 1, 'it,': 1, 'day': 1, 'is': 1})
['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike']
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay, that works but I am looking at how to do this using `filter()` with `lambda` to better understand if it is possible. If no one can come up with a way I am requesting, then I might reconsider your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Filter is quite intuitive:
You give it some kind of iterable and a constraint (your lambda function). It will then go over each item and only keep it, if it fullfills the constraint.

So in your case, you want to iterate the words of your sentence (thus split it first) and only keep them, if they are in your word list:

```
word_list = ['Geico','Mike']
a_string = "what day is it, Mike Mike Mike"
sets = filter(lambda x: x in word_list, a_string.split())
print(list(sets))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to filter the list  of a_string split by " "　
by whether each word is in word_list or not.

My answer:

```
sets = filter(lambda x:x in word_list, a_string.split())
```

or:

```
sets = [x for x in a_string.split() if x in word_list]
```